# Do two sibling elements have to be of the same type for their margins to collapse?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to improve this appearance of this Bootstrap 4 card:

[image]

As you can see, the spacing between the **About the gig** heading and the top **Date** item is larger than the spacing between the items themselves, and I'd like to make this this same. I notice, however, thath the margins don't collapse.

This shows that the `h3` element with **About the gig** has a `16px` bottom margin:

[image]

Conversely, the next element with the **Date** has a top margin of `24px`:

[image]

It would appear that the spacing between the **About the gig** and **Date** elements is `24px + 16px = 40px`, whereas with margin collapsing I would expect it to be `max(16px, 24px) = 24px`.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing, margin collapsing happens for "adjacent siblings". The examples there show elements of the same type (e.g., two `p` elements). Do elements have to be of the same type to be "adjacent siblings"? Why are the margins not collapsing in this case?

Comment: the type doesn't matter. are you inside a flexbox container? if so, margin doesn't collapse there

Answer (score 0):

you could give the top h3 an mb-0 class to remove its 16px of margin, this 16px is a default css rule for bootstrap, However, I recommend leaving it there and just removing it when you don't want it.

For me its set in _type.scss but it could be set elsewhere for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to h3 mb-0 (this class will remove the margin bottom).